# How do you fill in a space between two objects and leave the middle open?

Tags: modeling, objects

I'm not 100% sure how to word this so ill try to simplify it. Lets say you have 2 circles. One circle is inside the other like a doughnut. How would you fill the space between the 2 circles while leaving the middle empty if the two circles have a different number of vertices?

Comment: Like Denis said, it's Crtl + E to Bridge edge loops.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the circles as separate objects, first you need to join them into one mesh by selecting both and using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> shortcut.

Then switch to edit mode, select both circles, then hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and select *Bridge Edge Loops* from the menu.

[image]